# How to replace item in a list to empty string based on another nested list of same length based on condition

Tags: python, list

I have a header list as below:

```
h_list = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5']
```

Now I have data list (Nested):

```
d_list = [
[1, None, 3, ' ', 5],
[1, ' ', 2, ' ', 9]
]
```

Both lists are of same length every time, so I want to match in each list of nested list at same index position and if its all corresponding values are either `None` or `' '`, then replace the item from `h_list` to `' '` (Empty string)

My expected output is:

```
h_list = ['h1',' ','h3',' ','h5']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try a list comprehension:

```
h_list = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5']


d_list = [
[1, None, 3, ' ', 5],
[1, ' ', 2, ' ', 9]
]

empty = [' ', None]
h_list = [' ' if any(b[i] in empty for b in d_list) else v for i, v in enumerate(h_list)]
print(h_list)
```

Output:

```
['h1', ' ', 'h3', ' ', 'h5']
```

---

Breaking down this part of the code:

```
h_list = [' ' if any(b[i] in empty for b in d_list) else v for i, v in enumerate(h_list)]
```

First, lets have only

```
[(i, v) for i, v in enumerate(h_list)]
```

The above will be a list of the indices and values of each element in `h_list`.

Now, we use an `if` statement to determine when to add the `' '`. First, we need to recognize the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
any(b[i] in empty for b in d_list)
```

returns `True` if *any* of the arrays inside `d_list` at index `i` is in the `empty` list. We want `None` and `' '` to be in place for all the strings in `h_list` that its index returns a `' '` or `None` for any of the lists in `d_list`, so:

```
[' ' for i, v in enumerate(h_list) if any(b[i] in empty for b in d_list)]
```

Finally, we want to use the original string if *not* `any(b[i] in empty for b in d_list)`. For that, we use an `else` statement *(note that with an `else`, the statements get shifted to the left side of the `for` loop.)*:

```
h_list = [' ' if any(b[i] in empty for b in d_list) else v for i, v in enumerate(h_list)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work for your examples:

```
new_list = []
for orig_element, *values in zip(h_list, *d_list):
    new_list.append(orig_element if any(not (v is None or str(v).strip() == '') for v in values) else '')
```

If you want to modify the list in-place simply do:

```
for i, (orig_element, *values) in enumerate(h_list, *d_list):
    h_list[i] = orig_element if any(not (v is None or str(v).strip() == '') for v in values) else ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` with `all`:

```
h_list = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5']
d_list = [[1, None, 3, ' ', 5], [1, ' ', 2, ' ', 9]]
r = [' ' if all(k in {None, ' '} for k in j) else a for a, j in zip(h_list, zip(*d_list))]
```

Output:

```
['h1', ' ', 'h3', ' ', 'h5']
```

Answer (score 0):

***Basic solution***

```
h_list = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5']
d_list = [
[1, None, 3, ' ', 5],
[1, ' ', 2, ' ', 9]
]
# loop over d_list
for i in d_list:
# loop over inner list 
    for k in i:
# if type not int, give me space in that index
        if type(k)!=int:
            h_list[i.index(k)]=" "
h_list
```

Comment: The OP only specified `' '` and `None`, so perhaps different strings should still be kept in the resulting list.

Comment: @AnnZen yep, if they are able to understand the simple loops i wrote they can change the code and adapt it to their needs

Comment: Okay. Just though I'd warn you of reasons users might downvote a post, not that I think this post should be downvoted.